# Vicidial, dispo call url is not working

Tags: asterisk

I am using vicidial 2.6b0.5 asterisk 1.8

I set dispo-call-url as: `http://<ip_address>/test.php?lead_id=--A--lead_id--B--&dispo=--A--dispo--B--&phone_number=--A--phone_number--B--`

When agent disposition call after fillout all info fields this URL is not called.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add "VAR" Before the url like so:

```
VARhttp://servernameorip/pagename.php?leadid=--A--lead_id--B--&dispo=--A--dispo--B--
```